# how to get identity of an entity and set it as foreign key for another entity before savechanges?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i wanna add and an entity and get its identity before savechanges() and set it as a foreign key of another entity before savechanges in entity framework code first. is it possible?

first model

```
  public class A
{ 
   int AId { get; set; }
   string name { get; set; }
 }
```

second model

```
  public class B
{ 
   int BId { get; set; }
   int AId { get; set; }
   string name { get; set; }
 }
```

and.....

```
 db.As.Add(A);
 b.AId = A.Aid;
 db.savechanges();
```

is there any article which explains how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a property of type `A` in `B`.

```
public class A
{ 
   int AId { get; set; }
   string name { get; set; }
}

public class B
{ 
   int BId { get; set; }

   virtual A A { get; set; }
   int AId { get; set; }

   string name { get; set; }
}
```

Then assign the instance of `A` to that navigational property. EF will determine the insert/update order of entities resolve the FKs.

```
 b.A = a;
 db.As.Add(a);
 db.savechanges();
```